# hide div on jquery .load function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created this function in JQuery:

```
function OpenPage(pagename) {
    var page = pagename
    $('#LoadingDiv').show();
    $('.tabcontent').load(page);
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    window.onload = function () {
        $('#LoadingDiv').hide();
    }
}
```

it loads the selected page into a DIV using `.load`

before loading the page, its shows a div with a loading bar image, how can i hide this loading div once the page using `.load` has finished loading

i added `window.onload` at the end of my function but its not hiding the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the complete callback of `load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )`

```
function OpenPage(pagename) {
    var page = pagename
    $('#LoadingDiv').show();
    $('.tabcontent').load(page, function(){
        /* new html exists now */
        $('#LoadingDiv').hide();
    });
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");    
}
```

Reference: **[load() Docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use **Callback Function** of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function

> A callback function that is executed when the request completes.

*Change your code as*

```
function OpenPage(pagename) {
    var page = pagename
    $('#LoadingDiv').show();
    $('.tabcontent').load(page,function () {
        $('#LoadingDiv').hide();
    });
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
}
```